# Vertically Stacked Last DIV to fill/fit the rest of the Container Using Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a layout that would be responsive using Bootstrap 4. The problem I am having is when two divs wrap vertically for a smaller device the top div seems to push the lower div down exceeding the parent container (please see the images below). I want the lower div to fit with in the container, how can I achieve this using Bootstrap 4 or minimal css?

I added a yellow border on the bottom of the second div so we can see the push.

[Large device view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgqnP.png)

[Small device view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raMww.png)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.bottom-border {
  border-bottom: 50px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid p-0 h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col-md-8 bg-primary h-md-100 ">
        <div class="d-md-none text-center bg-primary">
          <h5>Left Section</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="d-none d-md-block m-3">
          <h1>Left Section</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 h-100 text-center bg-danger bottom-border">
        <h4>Right Section</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't understand your issue, your code is behaving as it is told based on your code

Comment: @IvanS95, please see the provided images and pay attention of the yellow border height.

Comment: I saw them, don't see what the issue is or your wording is off, it would be better to show what you expect the result to be... also you are using classes that do not exist in Bootstrap 4

Comment: @IvanS95, the bottom border of the red box is yellow and it's height is 50px. It is rendered as expected for large devices (see the image). For small devices when the divs are aliened vertically the yellow border height is obviously not 50px. You can see it in the second image I provided. That means that the red div is pushed down by the blue div.

Comment: Ahh, okay, but again, that's because of the `h-100` classes, the div that has that class uses the full height, it does not take into account other items on the same container... do this, remove the h-100 class only from the red div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you explained the significance of the border height, now I see what you mean, as mentioned previously, your `h-100` classes are the issue.

That class tells the element to use 100% of its parents height, since you put that class on the main `container` and on the `row` elements, those two are using the full screen's height since the container's parent is the browser window and the row parent is the container.

When you use that same class on the children div, in this case, the red div, it also tries to use the full height of its parent (the row), but it does not take into consideration the other item inside (the blue div), if you remove the `h-100` class from the red div, then each of them will use half the available space.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.bottom-border {
  border-bottom: 50px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row h-100 flex-column flex-md-row">
      <div class="col-md-8 bg-primary">
        <div class="d-md-none text-center bg-primary">
          <h5>Left Section</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="d-none d-md-block m-3">
          <h1>Left Section</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 flex-grow-1 text-center bg-danger bottom-border">
        <h4>Right Section</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @SlayerCat Thanks, if I understood OP correctly, the idea is for the items to use the full height available, but not more than that, the yellow border was not fully displayed because the red div had a 100% of the row's height, but the blue div was also there, so the red one was getting pushed 24px down (the blue div's height)

Comment: @IvanS95, thanks for the example but in my case the divs should not take same vertical space. Imaging the blue section is a header and the red portion is a chatbot that takes all available space on mobile but on desktop browser shows the full page, blue section at the left and red (chatbot) on the right (like dominos pizza chatbot site).

Comment: @A.G. Alright, I know what you need to do for that, I'll add the code, as a headsup, look into the `calc()` function in CSS and take a look at the pevious comment, basically, you have to set the height of the red div as something like `min-height: calc(100vh - 24px)`

Comment: @IvanS95, thanks, yes calc() would work on this case. Also giving bottom padding to the red div will work for my case. For both solutions you need to know the height of the blue div. I was hopping if there was a way of handling the problem without providing fixed height for the blue div. 
As for the yellow border, I added it to show that the red div is actually being pushed down. And yes, h-100 is the problem on the red div.

Comment: @A.G. I think there is a way, let me try something

Comment: @IvanS95, perfect thank you. It works the way I wanted. Great help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'd wish to keep the left and right div keep doesn't go on top of eachother?

col-**md** means everything that the window size is above 768px, keep that number of columns. if you use col-**sm**, it would be everything above 576px. If you just say col-***number***, you'll keep it responsive reguardeless of the container width.

```css
html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }

        .bottom-border {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<body>

<div class="container-fluid p-0 ">

        <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap bd-highlight text-center ">
            <div class="col-md-8  ">
                <div class="  h-100 bg-primary">left</div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-column col-md-4">
                <div class="  bg-danger ">Right</div>
                <div class=" bottom-border ">Bottom</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Also, since you're using Bootstrap 4, I'd also recommand checking [Flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/), which you basically put d-flex class on the parent and all the child will become responsive. You can make them even more precices with columns like you've did, but Flexbox is pretty powerful and really braindead to apply when you know how.

Comment: Hi @SlayerCat, I want it to be responsive and wrap the divs vertically as it does now. The only problem I have is that when they are vertically aligned the top div (blue) pushes the bottom div (red) down exceeding the parent container. You can see this because the yellow border of the red div is cut off about the same size as the top div's height. I looked at the flex box and even tried some combinations but without any success.

Comment: @A.G. If you are referring to the red div using all the remaining screen space, its because of the `h-100` class, remove those classes so each div only uses enough space to fit their content

Comment: @IvanS95, if I remove h-100 than div will take the height of its content. That is not what I want. I want it to take all available space of its parent but not exceed its parent's box.

Comment: @A.G. but they are not exceeding the container, the container is also using the full height available on the screen because of the `h-100` class, so the items inside are using the full height of their container, which is the full screen's height... try adding a border on each div (including the container) and you'll see that they are not exceeding it

Comment: @A.G. I'm still not 100% what you wish to achieve at the final result, but I've changed the snippet hoping it can give you more ideas.

Comment: @IvanS95, I can't understand how you can't see the obvious. I provided images and the description. And I don't understand why would you vote this issue down without understanding the problem.

Comment: @A.G. as you can see, I'm not the only one that is not clear about what you want, after you explained further on the comments, now I see what you issue seems to be, I downvoted because your question is not clear

Comment: @A.G.Alright I've re-changed the snippet again but didn't add any specific height on them. I though the pictures you've attached were your results and wanted something else, my bad.